# Systemd restart service if it's not listening to a port

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, systemd

I've been using Systemd for a while in Debian 8. I use the Restart=on-failure option to waken-up a service in case of failure.

I will like to know if there is a way to force the restart of the service if it is not listening to a specific port (even if the process stills running).

The reason of why I need that is because we are developing the new feature to will fix this issue but it will require a while. Meanwhile we need a workaround.

I have developed a script to check that status:

```
#! /bin/bash
PORTS=( 1452 542 )
for port in ${PORTS[@]}; do
    netstat -anp | grep $port > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        # Port blocked. Kill the running process and start it again after a while
done
```

This script is triggered periodically using the cron.I know it is a dirty trick. That's why I would like to integrate that behaviour in Systemd checking. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,

A.

Comment: You may even need deeper health checks, e.g. for when the port is listening but the service is black holing requests or worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you approach it differently and use a dedicated monitoring tool to accomplish this.

My favourite monitoring tool which allows services to be restarted in case they crash, or are not listening at their configured port(s) anymore is **monit**: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/monit

There are plenty of examples in the configuration file, on this site and elsewhere about setting it up. I will list an example to give you an idea how simple it is to use, the example uses init.d however it can easily be converted to use systemd.

To test a process exists and is listening on a specific port and to start it when this test fails:

```
check process example with pidfile /var/run/example.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/example start"
start program = "/etc/init.d/example stop"
if failed host 192.0.2.10 port 80 protocol http then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

You can leave out the ***protocol http*** part and monit will do just a simple tcp connect to test it out. The **protocol** argument does a more involved test to check whether something is actually responding to, for example, an http get request.

You need to make sure the process or service is started in such a way a corresponding **pid file** is created in /var/run. Monit itself doesn't take care of that. Normally if the service is started through an init script or systemd it should have a **pid file** in /var/run.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote it. I'm now using monit. Thanks for the answer. It's awesome :D